# better ways of writing nested for and if loops in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

I have a program which reads row by row from a database table (using pyodbc) and then do the following:

purpose: create an .hyper extract in tableau using python 3 API
main disadvantage: insert into .hyper file (tableau) is a row-wise operation and i have to explicitly assign each column of each row to a row object in tableau and then insert into the tableau hyper file.

code for review:

```
while row is not None:
    for i in range(0,colCount):
        if row[i] is not None:
            if columnDataTypes[i] == 15: 
                newrow.setCharString(i,row[i])
            elif columnDataTypes[i] == 12: 
                newrow.setDate(i, row[i].year, row[i].month, row[i].day)
            elif columnDataTypes[i] == 7: 
                newrow.setInteger(i,row[i])
            elif columnDataTypes[i] == 11:
                newrow.setBoolean(i,row[i])
            elif columnDataTypes[i] == 13:
                newrow.setDateTime(i,row[i])
            elif columnDataTypes[i] == 14:
                newrow.setDuration(i,row[i])
            elif columnDataTypes[i] == 16:
                newrow.set(i,row[i])
            else:
                newrow.setDouble(i,row[i])
    table.insert(newrow)
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

This works perfectly but wants to know if this can be re-written resulting either:
1. concise code (few lines)
2. better performance (w.r.t memory or reducing loops).

I have added "if row[i] is not None" loop because, if i do not add this, and if a column value is null then the script fails.

As am new python developer any inputs would help me better understand how python works.

my current python version: 3.7.2
windows 10 Enterprise
RAM: 32GB
i5 6300U CPU

Thanks in advance,
Srikanth

Comment: A very minor tweak, but you can change `if row[i] is not None:` to `if row[i]:` as a `None` value will equate to 0 or `False`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't know which class is `newrow`. I'll use the `RowClass` identifier for that.

(like `RowClass = newrow.__class__`)

The idea is to build a dictionary with integers as keys and functions to call as values, and look up the function with a default value of `setDouble`

Build this once at startup (else, it's less interesting performance-wise), which explains that I'm not using `newrow` and object notation, that would require rebuilding the dictionary at each new `newrow` value.

```
calldict = {
  15 : RowClass.setCharString,
  7  : RowClass.setInteger,
  11 : RowClass.setBoolean,
  12 : lambda self,i,r : RowClass(self,i,r.year,r.month,r.day)  # special case to match 2 arguments
  # same principle for others, of course
}
```

your loop with added, first function lookup, then function call:

```
while row is not None:
    for i in range(0,colCount):
        if row[i] is not None:

            # look up the function

            function_to_call = calldict.get(i,RowClass.setDouble)

            # call the function, passing the object as first argument:

            function_to_call(newrow,i,row[i])
```

Comment: It might be worth wrapping this in a `try`/`except` block and throwing a more specific exception if `calldict` doesn't contain the key.

Comment: no because it wouldn't emulate the original `else` statement that calls the "double" method.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jean-François Fabre.  Your solution works great.

Comment: Can i further use list comprehensions or map functions to improve the performance.

for example:

def func(colIndex):
    func = calldict.get(columnTypes[colIndex])
    return func(colIndex,row[colIndex])

while row:
    [func(i) for i in range(NrOfCols) if row[i] is not None]
    table.insert(newrow)
    row = cursor2.fetchone()

however, I'm still checking on the performance. For some reason, the if-elif code is running faster (20%) than the switch function using a dictionary method. Can you please give some ideas on performance improvements areas as well?

Thanks, Srikanth